# MagicalRecord/MagicalRecordXcode7CompatibilityMacros.h file not found in Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, magicalrecord

I downloaded and integrate copy of `MagicalRecord sdk 2.3.3` in my project.i am not using `cocoa pods`. why because cocoa pods does not provide `magical record 2.3.3 sdk`. but I cannot compile the My project. i am using `Xcode 7.2`. I get the following compile error:

> MagicalRecord/MagicalRecordXcode7CompatibilityMacros.h file not
>   found

Comment: You can use version 2.3.3 of MagicalRecord with CocoaPods if you put something like this in your Podfile: `pod 'MagicalRecord', :git => 'https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord.git', :tag => '2.3.3'`

Comment: @ThomasW actually Magicalrecord sdk 2.3.3 is provided cocoa pods.. so thats why i am downloaded and integrate into my code

Comment: Do you mean you no longer have this problem?

Comment: @ThomasW actually i am integrated magical record 2.3.1 past 6 months back. now magical record release new version i.e 2.3.3. so now i want to upgrade sdk into my project.. but cocoa pods does not provide updated version

Comment: In my previous comment I had the tag incorrect. This should work: `pod 'MagicalRecord', :git => 'https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord.git', :tag => 'v2.3.3'`

Comment: @ThomasW where should i mention this command?? "pod 'MagicalRecord', :git => 'https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord.git', :tag => 'v2.3.3'"

Comment: You put it in your `Podfile`, replacing any existing reference to MagicalRecord.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting derived data and cleaning worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Is the file visible in your navigator on the left? If so and the file is in red text color, then you can add this file by dragging it from the finder (search for the file with Spotlight) right into your project. If Xcode asked if it needs to copy the files if needed, check that box.

Comment: i am did like this.. but still i got same issue... thanks for your response. plz help me...

Comment: Did you find the missing file in Finder, or can't you find it at all?

Comment: Sweleson. i can able to find this file in finder. but still getting error

Comment: Did you import it again by deleting the red colored file in Xcode and dragging the one from the Finder in your project? (or by going to: File > Add Files to "Projectname" and navigating to your file). If the error still occurs, did you check Compile Sources under Project Name > Select your target > Build Phases > Compile Sources and than press the little 'plus' to add files

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened to me when I accidentally left Build Location set to Legacy (I set it when working on another project). Go to Preferences (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) -> Locations -> Advanced... and check if Build Location is set to Unique.